# Event not handled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, aura, lightning-events, component

I tried to create 2 component event just to see the difference but just the same seems like doesn't work for me. No error but was not handled on child component

```
handleRowAction :  function(component, event, helper){
    
  /*  var selectRow = event.getParam('selectedRows');
    var accountId = '';
    for ( var i=0; i< selectRow.length; i++ ) {
        accountId = selectRow[i].sobList.Id;
     }*/
    let childevt =component.getEvent("cmpEvent");// $A.get("e.c:ContactAccountEvent");//component.getEvent("cmpEvent");// 
        childevt.setParams({"message": "sample"}); 
    
         childevt.fire();
    
},
handleComponentEvent : function(component, event, helper){

    const evt = $A.get("e.c:contactCmpEvent");
    evt.setParams({"message": "sample"});
   
    evt.fire();
},
```

I tried using both component and application

Parent Component

```
<aura:registerEvent name="cmpEvent" type="c:ContactAccountEvent"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="childEvent" type="c:contactCmpEvent"/>
```

contactCmpEvent.evt

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT">
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="Account"/>
</aura:event>
```

contactCmpEvent.evt

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template" >
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

2nd component

```
<aura:attribute name="AccountIdsas" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="messageFromEvent" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="sample1" event="c:ContactAccountEvent"
   action="{!c.handleComponentEvent}"/>

<aura:handler name="sample2" event="c:contactCmpEvent"
   action="{!c.anotherComponent}"/>
<lightning:card title="All Contacts">
    <aura:set attribute="actions">
        <lightning:button label="New"
                          onclick="{!c.handleComponentEvent}"/>
    </aura:set>
    
    <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            sample ambot nimo yawa ka
      </p>
        <p>{!v.messageFromEvent}</p>

</lightning:card>
```

my component controller

```
handleComponentEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert("Sample");
},

anotherComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
    alert("sample1231");
   
},
```

I really don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component events can't travel "down" the hierarchy directly, beyond the point where the event is fired. Usually, the parent component would just set an attribute on the child, which would trigger an aura:valueChange event on the child component, which it then handles. This is why your component event does not work.

---

Application event handlers must **not** specify a "name" attribute, as this causes it to be registered as a component event. Thus, you can do:

```
<aura:handler event="c:contactCmpEvent" action="{!c.anotherComponent}"/>
```

To handle an application event.